# Could not get unknown property 'apkNames' in android gradle plugin 4.1.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using this code in build.gradle:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.packageApplicationProvider.configure { packageApplicationTask ->
            doLast {
                packageApplicationTask.apkNames.each { apkName ->
                    def apkDir = "./build/outputs/apk/${flavorName}/${buildType.name}"
                    def apkDestName = apkName.replace("app-", "stickerly-android-" + variant.versionName + "-").replace(".apk", "-" + getDate() + ".apk")

                    println "#####Rename ${variant.name} Apk File"
                    copy {
                        from("$apkDir/$apkName").into(apkDir).rename { String fileName -> apkDestName }
                    }

                    println "#####Copy mapping File"
                    def mappingDir = "./build/outputs/mapping/${flavorName}${buildType.name.capitalize()}"
                    copy {
                        from("$mappingDir/mapping.txt").into(mappingDir).rename {
                            "mapping-stickerly-${variant.versionName}.txt"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I rename apk file and copy mapping file. I worked in android gradle plugin 4.0, but it does not work in 4.1 with this message

> Where:
>
> Script '/Users/snow/workspace/stickerly-android/app/build-android-extra.gradle' line: 5
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:packageExternalArm8Debug'.
> Could not get unknown property 'apkNames' for task ':app:packageExternalArm8Debug' of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.

I think API has changed but I can not find any documents. Someone can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

property apkNames is removed in AGP 4.1

you can try this

```
gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { Task task, TaskState state ->
    if (!state.failure
            && task.project.name == project.name
            && task.name.startsWith("package")
            && !task.name.endsWith("UnitTest")) {
        def outputDir = task.outputDirectory.getAsFile().get()
        task.variantOutputs.getOrNull()?.each { variant ->
            println "" + outputDir + "/" + variant.outputFileName.get()
        }
    }
}
```

add this at the end of your build.gradle file.

change `println` to whatever logic you want.

by the way, if you want to check the properties you may use, just add gradle plugin as a dependency of your project, click `Sync` in Android Stuido, then you can find it in External Librarys (key map: Command + 1, and switch to project view).

like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
}
```

and these properties and tasks are intentionally invisible in lib `com.android.tools.build:gradle-api`, modifications in future releases are expected.